# Change the object after being returned in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa, nscoder

`NSKeyedUnarchiver` which is a concrete subclass of `NSCoder` works like magic.

**Please take a look at this example:**

I have 2 classes, `Person` and `CreditCard`

```
class Person: NSObject, NSCoding {
    var creditCard: CreditCard

    init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "creditCard") as? CreditCard            
    }
}

class CreditCard: NSObject, NSCoding {
    weak var person: Person

    init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "person") as? Person
    }
}
```

As you can see, the objects are connected to each others. What's amazing about `NSKeyedUnarchiver` is how it can handle inifinite loop. If a coder follows every link and blindly encodes each object it encounters, this circular reference will generate an infinite loop:

`Person -> CreditCard -> Person -> CreditCard -> ....infinite loop`

**Below are the steps:**

1. When initializing `Person` class, `aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "creditCard") as? CreditCard` is called.
   This method calls `init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)` in the `CreditCard` class.
2. But the `CreditCard` class cannot be initialized because there is `aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "person")` in the initializer. And this method will call `init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)` in the `Person` class.
3. It will repeat infinitely and both `Person` and `CreditCard` will not be able to be initialized, like egg and chicken.

I tried to find how `NSKeyedArchiver` is able to prevent this loop.

**According to this:** 
https://github.com/gnustep/libs-base/blob/master/Source/NSKeyedUnarchiver.m

The trick is to use `o = [className allocWithZone: _zone];` (line 237) without `init` and store that to an array. For the next time when we call the `aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey:)`, instead of calling init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) it will return that object in the array (line 174).

I tried to replicate this behavior in Swift for my library. But I couldn't find a way to do this in Swift because we can't do `alloc` without `init` in Swift. Any suggestion? Maybe rewriting the bytes in the object pointer will work?

Comment: It is unclear what your goal or problem is here. Are you trying to use `NSCoder` itself? Are you trying to write some code and wish to try implement the *technique* that `NSCoder` uses as you see it as a solution to a requirement you have in your code? Etc. I suggest you edit the question, make your issue/question clearer, include your own code from your Swift library as needed, etc. Someone then will probably be able to help you.

Comment: @CRD Thank you for your reply. I’m trying to write a library that implements the technique that `NSKeyedUnarchiver` uses. `NSKeyedUnarchiver` is able to avoid the circular reference loop because it can generate an empty placeholder object using ’allocWithZone’, and return it. That placeholder object can be initialized later. In Swift, there is no such functionality. I want to include my library source code but it’s too big to post it with the question. I’ll attach a github link later.

Comment: You should reduce your code to just what is required to show the problem and put it in a new question (this one already has a close vote against it) explaining what you need to achieve. General approaches you can explore are indirection and/or two-passes. But without specific details nobody can help you other than by guessing. HTH